# I want to get the lines from a file which matches a given pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find the number of occurrences of the below string from `file(say D:\Test\test.txt)` where `XXXXXX` can be anything (combination of numbers and alphabetical characters of any length).

```
/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS
```

Comment: # below is my code
f=open("D:\\Test\\test.txt",'r')
R=f.read()
l1=re.findall("/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=*",R)
print(len(l1))

Comment: If the file is reading OK, I'd just remove that from your question. You can edit your question to incorporate the code you've posted here to preserve it for posterity and format it nicely. Posting sample input and expected output is very helpful. All of this helps improve the quality and relevance of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You can use the `.` dot to match any character, add a `*?` lazy quantifier and include the `#JOBS` literal:

```
import re

file_content = """
/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=job1#JOBS
something something
 blah blah /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=job2#JOBS
 foobar
"""

matches = re.findall(r"/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=.*?#JOBS", file_content)  

print(len(matches)) # => 2
```

If your `.*?` might be multiline, add the dotall `re.S` flag to the `findall` call.

Answer (score 0):

This expression with a simple capturing group might do that:

```
(\/Operator command:.+?#JOBS)
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/wm1NTR/1/)

or this one, if we might want more constraints:

```
(\/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=.+?#JOBS)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/0Kf1hc/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(\/Operator command:.+?#JOBS)"

test_str = ("/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue \n\n\n"
    "/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue /Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue \n"
    "/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue \n\n"
    "/Operator command: SUBMIT JOB=XXXXXX#JOBS Anything we wish after and continue ")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]